# Getting mp3/mp4 Audio/Video file details using Java/Android

Tags: java, android

I am want to know the Album Name, Artist Name, Duration, Genre etc from a mp3 audio file or mp4 Video file that is available in another Android phone from my Android phone. Both the phones are in the same LAN/WiFi. I used the API `MediaMetadataRetriever` to get these details. But this API is useful to get the song details from the local file.

How to get the song details if the file is in a network.

Any suggestions on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Get the details locally and convert them into bytes and pass them to the client